# hide edit item ribbon in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, list-view, ribbon

I wish to hide the edit items ribbon in one of the webpart pages where i am displaying a list view webpart.

I found the solution in this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116001/hide-disable-ribbon-bar-buttons-with-client-side-code), **I am able to hide the ribbons.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideEdit() {
        var edit = document.getElementById("Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.EditItem-Large");
        edit.style.display = "none";
    }       
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideEdit");
</script>
```

The problem is , i am getting some java-script errors in my console when i use the code

The error details are below

```
MyPage.aspx:751 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at hideEdit (MyPage.aspx:751)
    at eval (eval at ProcessOnLoadFunctionNames (init.js:1), <anonymous>:1:34)
    at ProcessOnLoadFunctionNames (init.js:1)
    at ProcessDefaultOnLoad (init.js:1)
    at NotifyEventAndExecuteWaitingJobs (init.js:1)
    at NotifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs (init.js:1)
    at $_global_core (core.js:1)
    at core.js:1
```

I tried to manually locate the element in the console using

```
document.getElementById("Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.EditItem-Large")
```

and

```
$('#Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.EditItem-Large')
```

both are returning `null` and `undefined`. I can't figure out this error and how is the above code working?

1. Even if i change the id to something else i was able to hide the
   ribbons. **why is it working?**
2. If the above queries are returning null it means the code
   is incorrect right?
3. Where to get the proper ids of these ribbons?
4. Did MS changed the ids in SharePoint-Online?

**UPDATE**

The above code **achieves the desired functionality** but i can't comprehend how. because the element is not present in any of my source code or in console.

So, please explain **why it works even though element is absent** and way to avoid the error.

**EDIT:**
 I tried escaping the `.` using `\.` but still the element is not present

Answer (score 2):

It won't work because the ribbon needs time to be loaded. It's better to use CSS here.

You can add:

```
<style>#Ribbon\.ListForm\.Display\.Manage\.EditItem-Large { display:none }</style>
```

Comment: thanks for the tip using CSS.. somehow even after loading the page, and waiting for minutes and running `$('#Ribbon\.ListForm\.Display\.Manage\.EditItem-Large')` returns undefined/null.. doesn't that mean the element id is wrong? Did MS change the id in SharePoint Online..

Comment: Problem in my scenario is **it is working** but I don't know why.. :(

Comment: You can click right on the Edit icon and select "Inspect element" (in a modern browser) and check what is the id for your element in the web console of your browser.

Comment: for the Item ribbon it was `Ribbon.ListItem-title` and for Edit Item button it was `Ribbon.ListItem.Manage.EditProperties-Large` both of which very different from `Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.EditItem-Large` .. which is why **it is confusing why the code works while still throwing the error**..

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
document.getElementById("Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.EditItem-Large");
```

to

```
document.getElementById("Ribbon\.ListForm\.Display\.Manage\.EditItem-Large");
```

You need to escape the `.` to make the selector work

Comment: It is still throwing null :( . I searched for that id in the source code but it is not there.. It is like an invalid id. which generates error and somehow prevent the ribbon..

Answer (score 0):

A the error indicates:

```
MyPage.aspx:751 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
at hideEdit (MyPage.aspx:751)
```

your hideEdit() function is trying to get the style property in order to do the hiding. Looking at your function code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideEdit() {
    var edit = document.getElementById("Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.EditItem-Large");
    edit.style.display = "none";
}    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideEdit");
```

We can see that the document.getElementById() function failed to find the object thus returning null. In most cases in JavaScript when this happens, it's because the page load isn't complete. Try encapsulating your action in the $(document).ready() method like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {var edit = document.getElementById("Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.EditItem-Large");
    edit.style.display = "none";
}</script>
```

This way, your function should only execute after the page has fully loaded.

Comment: even after the page is fully loaded .. i ran the code on console and i got null. I checked the source code for the page and find that id anywhere.

Comment: I dunno why it is working... eventhough it is throwing error it hides the ribbons except Browse and page

Comment: and `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` usually executes after DOM is loaded and rendered... so it executes after document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

To **Hide edit item ribbon in SharePoint online**

Use the below script :

```
$('a[id*="Ribbon.Documents.Manage.EditProperties-Large"]').remove();
```

To **Hide delete item ribbon in SharePoint online**

```
$('a[id*="Ribbon.Documents.Manage.Delete-Medium"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use below script to hide the ribbon. It will work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "none";
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

why are you complicating the basic functionality of a SharePoint page? "Permissions" should be significantly easier to manage and is one of SharePoint's core strengths

[Solution](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-best-practices-for-managing-how-people-use-your-team-site-95e83c3d-e1b0-4aae-9d08-e94dcaa4942e)

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, a setting where a visitor can only add a new list and view their own without being able to make any other edits. Even better, a way to have just a "New" button listed that just popped up a list to edit and save. There is no role with just that option so I have to give them contributor role in order to create a list.